# Microsoft.Phone.Shell.dll is missing?

Tags: windows-phone-7, dll, windows-phone-7.1

i just start developping windows phone apps through using silverlight & windows phone SDK 7.1 frameworks and while i am open a new project for developping an App[lication] bar i noticed that i need a reference [Microsoft.Phone.Shell] well .. i try to add it .. after a multiple of effort of searching i see that i didn't have the .Dll file → [Microsoft.Phone.Shell.dll]  in the directory of my installed .Dll files .. so Plz my friends i need an answer or a  hint to complete that app ....

Comment: Microsoft.Phone.Shell namespace reside in Microsoft.Phone.dll. So what you need actually is add reference to Microsoft.Phone.dll, and declare namespace for Microsoft.Phone.Shell. And those two steps are already done by visual studio when you create new WP project from template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do to be able to use Application Bar are:

1. Add reference to `Microsoft.Phone.dll`
2. Add following two namespaces

   xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
3. Then you can use the application bar :

---

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    ...
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    ...
    >
    ...

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: where do you find that d.. please ?